# Google cloud storage for a facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe, facebook-apps, facebook-page, google-cloud-storage

I have made a facebook fan-gate app.  I was wondering if anyone had any success using google cloud storage instead of their own server storage.

I tried amazon cloud storage but apparently that will not work for a reason that is out of my realm of expertise.

I have tried a few times but couldn't get it to work.

dont know what to use for the
Page URL
Secure Page URL
Tab URL
Secure Tab URL
or APP domain

Comment: Good question, but I don't know.  I've upvoted this for you in hopes you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

We use Amazon S3 for storing files for an facebook fan page app.

You can see it here https://www.facebook.com/Trustpilot?sk=app_264324680252883 and the html file shown in the iframe is actually just https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/s.trustpilot.com/facebook/163506/70729414688.html.

Facebook hide this if you look at the source code as they use an proxy. I thing they do that for preventing people to have tracking software such as google analytics.

Comment: I tried amazon s3 couldn't get it to work...https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=62118

Comment: what we do is to have page on an 'real' webserver this then redirects to the S3 stored page depending of which page did the request. We do the redirect server side but you don't have to. Facebook post to the url you enter in the "Page Tab URL". They post an signed_request that contains information about the Facebook Page like page_id.

Comment: I see, that's hard for me to follow...a bit over my head, time to do some more learning i guess.